# Standard deviation from numpy 2d histogram

Tags: python, numpy, histogram2d

Is there a method to determine the standard deviation in each bin using the numpy histrogram2d method, given a series of 2d coordinates along with weighted values for each coordinate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not *directly* possible with numpy's `histrogram2d` but with [scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d.html) it can be done quite easily.

```
from scipy import stats

x = np.random.rand(10000)
y = np.random.rand(10000)
z = np.random.rand(10000)
binx = np.linspace(0,x.max(), 100)
biny = np.linspace(0,y.max(), 100)
hist = stats.binned_statistic_2d(x, y, z, statistic='std', bins=[binx, biny])
plot_x, plot_y = np.meshgrid(binx, biny)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
pc = ax.pcolormesh(plot_x, plot_y, hist[0].T, cmap="inferno")
ax.set_aspect('equal')
cbar=fig.colorbar(pc,shrink=0.725)
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

The `statistic` option can also take different things like `mean`, `median` or a user-defined function, see the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d.html) for more details.

Comment: Hope this can be of help to someone because I just stumbled upon the same problem and found this solution.

Comment: In addition, one could of course also first use `histogram2d` to derive the bins & co automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure what are you asking, could you post your code?

I generally plot std on hist drawing verticals lines as follows:

```
plt.axvline(x=np.mean(data)-np.std(data), ls = "--", color='#2ca02c', alpha=0.7)
plt.axvline(x=np.mean(data)+np.std(data), ls = "--", color='#2ca02c', alpha=0.7)
```

Where "data" is a dictionary with all the values[image]

Comment: I have a series of lat/long points and a measurement for each of these.

First I find the sum of these measurements in a grid over a map. I split the map up into say 200 equal bins, using the np.histogram2d method below:  

    sums, _, _ = np.histogram2d(cleanlat, cleanlon, [lat_bins, lon_bins], weights=measurement)

With lat/lon_bin indicating my gridding pattern, and cleanlat/lon indicating my measurement points, and measurement as my measurement values. 

I was wondering if I can find the standard deviation in each bin of the weights, rather than just the sum of the weights

Comment: Try to have a look at this one: the guide shows how to calculate the mean of each bin. Maybe it is possible to do std as well [link] (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html[/link]

Comment: Thanks very much! I'd been searching for ages for something like that!